# Design an RF amplifier for a photodiode

Tags: amplifier, rf, circuit-design, photodiode, optics

I've been asked to present a possible solution to design an optical system aimed at estimating the arrival time of the following light signal:

$$s(t)=[\Sigma_{i=1}^∞rect(\frac{t-t_i}{T})]\cdot Acos(ω_0 t+φ)$$

with:

- ω0=2π∙50MHz
- T=100us
- t(i+1)-ti=200us
- Pin=-30dBm

**Requirements for the amplifier:**

- Use a photodiode
- 20Ω input impedance
- 50Ω output impedance
- Responsivity 0.8 A/W;
- Minimum output voltage 100mVpp
- Sufficient bandwidth for the input signal

**What I am asking you**

I do not want to ask you to do my homework. But I do not know how to start since I have lots of doubts. So, I'm asking to get some clarifications and suggestions that will help me proceed. I'll put here what I'll get with your advice. Precisely:

**1. A responsivity of 0.8 A/W is required**. Is it only a property of the photodiode or does it depend also on the surrounding circuitry? If I choose a photodiode with such a responsivity, can I say this requirement is filled?

**2.** I've sketched **the behaviour of the incident light signal**:

[image]

Can I assume the photodiode to be linear so that the current it generates has the same behaviour?

**3. About the bandwidth** , I have done the following thinking. The spectrum of a rect is a sinc, and the spectrum of a train of rects is a sampled sinc. The latter will be shifted at ω0=2π∙50MHz. The main lobe of a sinc is large 1/(rect duration) = 1/T = 10kHz. Hence, if we decide to let the main lobe pass, we need an amplifier which works from 40MHz to 60MHz. Do you agree with me?

**4. What might be a reason for asking a 20Ω input impedance?** Is it just a casual homework requirement? As the photodiode behaves like a real current source, wouldn't be better if it were connected to a 0Ω load?

**5. What is the simplest circuital topology** you know which has the degrees of freedom for the requirements?

The simplest I know is this one:

[image]

But I would have to add a 20Ω series resistance at input and a 50Ω parallel resistance at output to fill the requirements. That does not seem to me a good idea.

Can you suggest a topology which lets me fill those requirements? The simpler the topology (also by neglecting some parasitic behaviours) the better it is since I'm newbie on this topic.

**6.** Does the amplifier have to be necessarily **bandpass** between 40 and 60MHz, or can it be also a low pass filter (from 0 to 60MHz) or high pass filter (from 40MHz) to keep the initial signal shape?

Comment: For your point 2) the light is probably like that (monochromatic), but the diode will react to the envelope, so more or less a square wave signal. But then I see that om0 is 50 MHz, that is not a frequecy for a light signal, and cannot be even the modulation of its intensity because it goes to negative values.

Comment: @andrea Do you think the light should be modulated by a signal like (A+Acos(w0t+phi))? It may be a mistake of the requirement

Comment: You need to know the wavelength or spectrum of your incoming light to be able to address the responsivity requirement.

Comment: You should look in to reverse biasing the photo diode. It's not clear in your schematic how you plan to bias the diode.

Comment: @Kinka-Byo I only noted that there are parameters not matching what one could expect: 50 MHz is not the frequency of light (of course), it should be then a modulation of the intensity (maybe, let's say yes), but cannot be negative then.

Answer (score 1):

OTA’s are used to amplify current sources and the feedback R is the input resistance. The output resistance rises to the open loop Rs of any negative feedback amplifier as the gain reduces to u it’s at max GBW product thus a 50 ohm driver is a special consideration for video amps with high gain at 50 MHz and largely determined by the collector R.

As you may have already guessed -30 dBm is 1uW optical and so 0.8uA/uW into 20 Ohms is only 16uV so you need a large voltage gain with a 50 Ohm output impedance after the OTA to get your required output voltage. RC =T feedback must match RC=T of the PD for a flat response up to the GBW product (-3dB) of the OTA IC.

Parasitics of the geometric pF are also important in the layout.

That should get you started. If you get stuck , I’m sure you can find an answer with a schematic on the web, but only if you get stuck ;).  You might be expected to design this with discrete FETS but you will need more than 50MHz BW.

Comment: I immediately got stuck :( With a -30dBm power, that means 1uW, the photodiode current will be 0.8uA. Is that the peak amplitude of the current signal, or the rms value?

Comment: I’m not sure , assume it’s peak power , besides what’s a few more dB when you need at least 70 dB gain or GBW=3.5GHz then factor another 6dB for 50 ohm load loss.

Answer (score 0):

The 20 Ohm input resistance of your "transimpedance" amplifier is likely needed for stability.
A photodiode may have too much capacitance to hook to the inverting input of your op-amp.
It is double trouble if the photocell leads are long making a tuned circuit you don't want.
You will likely need a small resistance in that path at least for stability.
The capacitor across the feedback resistor can be quite small.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. A responsivity of 0.8 A/W is required. Is it only a property of the photodiode or does it depend also on the surrounding circuitry?

Property of the photodiode.  For a conventional photodiode each photon gives you one electron, but since shorter wavelength photons are more energic you get fewer per watt.  In addition photodiodes aren't 100% efficient, typical quantum efficiency might be in the range of 0.2 to 0.9 depending on the wavelength and semiconductor.

> Can I assume the photodiode to be linear so that the current it generates has the same behaviour?

If reverse biased then yes it will be extremely linear.

> 4. What might be a reason for asking a 20Ω input impedance? Is it just a casual homework requirement? As the photodiode behaves like a real current source, wouldn't be better if it were connected to a 0Ω load?

If you do a conventional transimpedance amplifier, then usually you do 0 ohms.  The other option is a voltage amplifier where you have the current drop across an input resistance.  In this case it sounds like they want you to do the latter but I would ask questions here, the meaning of your spec is unclear.

> 6. Does the amplifier have to be necessarily bandpass between 40 and 60MHz, or can it be also a low pass filter (from 0 to 60MHz) or high pass filter (from 40MHz) to keep the initial signal shape?

Low pass would work.